# Python output in regular expressions

Tags: python

Hey community I'm new in python and I have a question may be this have been answered before but I want to know if that's possible

I have this python code:

```
import re

file = open("address.txt","r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
content = content.split('LAN ')[1:]
dic = {}
for lan in content:
    dic[int(lan[0])] = lan[1:] 



def address(lan_index):
    address = re.findall('address\s(.*?)\s',dic[lan_index] )
    print 'LAN',lan_index,":",address
    return address
address(1)
```

where my output is:

> LAN 1 : ['192.168.0.0']

Is it possible to remove `['']` and print only the `address`?
for example something like this:

> LAN 1 : 192.168.0.0 <--- That's the output I want.

Comment: Try printing `address[0]`

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list of all the matches (as far as I know), since it found out only one, it returned list with one value. You need to access it as @Evert wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address` is the result of a `re.findall` so it comes in the form of a `list`. If you want the (only) result that is supposed to be returned take the first item from that list:

```
print 'LAN', lan_index, ":", address[0]
```

I would also suggest to make sure an address was found:

```
def address(lan_index):
    address = re.findall('address\s(.*?)\s',dic[lan_index] )
    if len(address) > 0:
        print 'LAN', lan_index, ":", address[0]
    else:
        print 'No address was found!'
    return address
```

Comment: Also, consider using `match = re.search(...)` [(doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead of `re.findall(...)` if you're only interested in one match instead of every match. You can extract the matched string using `address = match.group()` [(doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) if a match was found.

Comment: Thank you a lot Uriel, worked exactaly as expected, thanks for your time :)!. Also thank you @suspicousdog I'll read a lot more about it.